# How do I send a parameter list to be used as arguments when a delegate is invoked?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, delegates, arguments

I've implemented a simple extension method in my asp.net mvc 3 app to pull objects out of session using generics:

```
public static T GetVal<T>(this HttpSessionStateBase Session, string key, Func<T> getValues)
    {
        if (Session[key] == null)
            Session[key] = getValues();

        return (T)Session[key];
    }
```

This works great if getValues() doesn't require any arguments.

I was attempting to write an overload that takes in **params object[] args** to allow me to pass arguments if necessary to the getValues() function, but I don't know what the syntax is to apply those variables to the function.

Is this even possible? Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would argue that you shouldn't need to do this - the caller can handle that with a lambda expression. For example:

```
int x = session.GetVal<int>("index", () => "something".IndexOf("o"));
```

Here we're capturing the idea of calling `IndexOf` on `"something"` passing in the argument `"o"`. All of that is captured in a simple `Func<int>`.

Comment: Ok Jon, you're getting the upvotes here...what would my GetVal function look like in this case?

Comment: Yeah just saw that...awesome! So in my () => I can call any method I want, and it passes the results or the actual method to the getValues call in the extension? I guess I'm not fully clear on what's happening here.

Comment: @IronicMuffin: The compiler will create a delegate for you; the code will only be called if the delegate is invoked. Time to read up on lambda expressions, I think :)

Comment: I use lambdas often with extension methods...just never saw the empty () => myFunc() format. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add an overload to your function

```
public static T GetVal<T>(this HttpSessionStateBase Session, string key, Func<IList<object>,T> getValues, IList<object> args)
{
    if (Session[key] == null)
        Session[key] = getValues(args);

    return (T)Session[key];
}
```

Comment: So this would be called with a new IList() { value1, value2, ... } ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to define your own delegate rather than Func.  The following will work perfectly here:

```
public delegate TResult ParamsFunc<TResult>(params object[] args);
```